# multivariate Effective Sample Size (multiESS): choice of batch size

Tags: sample-size, markov-chain-montecarlo

(*For those interested, my MATLAB implementation of* `multiESS` *is available [here](https://github.com/lacerbi/multiESS).*)

---

I am re-implementing the multivariate Effective Sample Size (multiESS) estimator for MCMC from [Vats et al. (2015)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07713v1.pdf). User @Greenparker gave an excellent description of the method in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224244/80479); I copy here the relevant part since I couldn't do better (check her full answer for more details):

> The multivariate ESS returns one number for the effective sample size for the quantities you want to estimate; and it does so by accounting for all the cross-correlations in the process. [...] Suppose you are interested in the $p$-vector of means of the posterior distribution. The mESS is defined as follows
>   $$\text{mESS} = n \left(\dfrac{|\Lambda|}{|\Sigma|}\right)^{1/p}. $$
>   Here
>
> 1. $\Lambda$ is the covariance structure of the posterior (also the asymptotic covariance in the CLT if you had independent samples)
> 2. $\Sigma$ is the asymptotic covariance matrix in the Markov chain CLT (different from $\Lambda$ since samples are correlated.
> 3. $p$ is number of quantities being estimated (or in this case, the dimension of the posterior.
> 4. $|\cdot|$ is the determinant.
> 5. [$n$ is the number of samples.]
>
> mESS can be estimated  by using the sample covariance matrix to estimate $\Lambda$ and the batch means covariance matrix to estimate $\Sigma$. This has been coded in the function `multiESS` in the R package [mcmcse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcmcse/index.html).

The only nontrivial part in the algorithm is the batch estimation of $\Sigma$, which requires a choice of the batch size $1 \le b_n \le n$.

The default choice for $b_n$ in `multiESS` is $\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor$. However, the method to choose $b_n$ is the paper is not completely clear and it is somewhat arbitrary (e.g., the authors sometimes pick $\lfloor n^{1/3} \rfloor$). Also, the authors show that the choice of $b_n$ should depend on the mixing time of the Markov chain, with slow-mixing processes requiring a larger $b_n$.

In practice, the choice of $b_n$ can affect the output of $\text{mESS}$ by an order of magnitude or even more.

As a practical, conservative choice, I am thinking of using for analyses the lower bound $\text{mESS}^*$ defined as follows:
$$
\text{mESS}^* \equiv \min_{b_\text{min} \le b_n \le b_\text{max}} \text{mESS}(b_n)$$
where $b_\text{min} \ge 1$ is a small number (e.g., $b_\text{min} \equiv \lfloor n^{1/4} \rfloor$) and $b_\text{max} \le n$ is taken such that there is a reasonable number of batches to average over (e.g., $b_\text{max} \equiv \lfloor n/10 \rfloor$).

Does this sound sensible? Any other suggestion on how to choose $b_n$ in an objective way?

(A quick test suggests that $\text{mESS}^*$ seems to be not as conservative as taking the minimum of the univariate ESS across dimensions; so it probably strikes a good balance.)

Comment: Aside from my long answer, what you're doing is ok, as long as you decrease the possible values of $b_n$ the way I described below. Cause otherwise you might be getting very bad estimates.

Comment: Yeah @Greenparker, when implementing it I realised that of course I need to have $b_n$ less than $n$ such that $a_n$ (number of batches) is a reasonable number -- otherwise the estimates would oscillate wildly or simply explode. I'll fix it in my question -- thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. FYI, this problem is also there in the univariate setting, and is not only in the multivariate ESS.

This is the best I can think of right now. The choice of choosing the optimal batch size is an open problem. However, it is clear that in terms of asymptotics, $b_n$ should increase with $n$ (this is mentioned in the paper also I think. In general it is known that if $b_n$ does not increase with $n$, then $\Sigma$ will not be strongly consistent).

So instead of looking at $1 \leq b_n \leq n$ it will be better (or at least theoretically better) to look at $b_n = n^{t}$ where $0 < t < 1$. Now, let me first explain how the batch means estimator works. Suppose you have a $p$-dimensional Markov chain $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_n$. To estimate $\Sigma$, this Markov chain is broken into batches ($a_n$ batches of size $b_n$), and the sample mean of each batch is calculated ($\bar{Y}_i$).

$$ \underbrace{X_1, \dots, X_{b_n}}_{\bar{Y}_{1}}, \quad   \underbrace{X_{b_n+1}, \dots, X_{2b_n}}_{\bar{Y}_{2}}, \quad \dots\quad ,\underbrace{X_{n-b_n+1},\dots,  X_{n}}_{\bar{Y}_{a_n}}.$$

The sample covariance (scaled) is the batch means estimator.

If $b_n = 1$, then the batch means will be exactly the Markov chain, and your batch means estimator will estimate $\Lambda$ and not $\Sigma$. If $b_n = 2$ then that means you are assuming that there is only a significant correlation upto lag 1, and all correlation after that is too small. This is likely not true, since lags go upto over and above 20-40 usually.

On the other hand, if $b_n > n/2$ you have only one batch, and thus will have no batch means estimator. So you definitely want $b_n < n/2$. But you also want $b_n$ to be low enough so that you have enough batches to calculate the covariance structure.

In Vats et al., I think they choose $n^{1/2}$ for when its slowly mixing and $n^{1/3}$ when it is reasonable. A *reasonable* thing to do is to look at how many significant lags you have. If you have large lags, then choose a larger batch size, and if you have small lags choose a smaller batch size. If you want to use the method you mentioned, this I would restrict $b_n$ to be over a much smaller set. Maybe let $T = \{ .1, .2, .3, .4, .5\}$, and take
$$ \text{mESS}^* = \min_{t \in T, b_n = n^t} \text{mESS}(b_n)$$

From my understanding of the field, there is still some work to be done in choosing batch sizes, and a couple of groups (including Vats et al) are working on this problem. However, the ad-hoc way of choosing batch sizes by learning from the ACF plots seems to have worked so far.

**EDIT**------

Here is another way to think about this. Note that the batch size should ideally be such that the  batch means $\bar{Y}$ have no lag associated with it. So the batch size can be chosen such that the acf plot for the **batch means** shows no significant lags.

Consider the AR(1) example below (this is univariate, but can be extended to the multivariate setting). For $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$.
$$x_t = \rho x_{t-1} + \epsilon. $$

The closer $\rho$ is to 1, the slower mixing the chain is. I set $\rho = .5$ and run the Markov chain for $n = 100,000$ iterations. Here is the ACF plot for the Markov chain $x_t$.

[image]

Seeing how there are lags only up to 5-6, I choose $b_n = \lfloor n^{1/5} \rfloor$, break the chain into batches, and calculate the batchmeans. Now I present the ACF for the batch means.

[image]

Ah, there is one significant lag in the batch means. So maybe $t = 1/5$ is too low. I choose $t = 1/4$ instead (you could choose something inbetween also, but this is easier), and again look at the acf of the batch means.

[image]

No significant lags! So now you know that choosing $b_n = \lfloor n^{1/4} \rfloor$ gives you big enough batches so that subsequent batch means are approximately uncorrelated.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! (Also, thanks for fixing the typo in my original post, sorry about that.)