# What batch size should I use to estimate the multivariate effective sample size (multiESS) if I have virtually no autocorrelation?

Tags: bayesian, sample-size, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

I am trying to estimate the multivariate effective sample size of an MCMC posterior sample with 8 parameters. For that, I am using the function `multiESS` in the R package mcmcse. One of the arguments of this function is batch size, the choice of which significantly influences the estimation of the multivariate ESS.

User @Greenparker gave incredibly helpful answers to previous questions regarding `multiESS`. Answering a [question specifically about the choice of batch size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224553), she suggests the following:

> A reasonable thing to do is to look at how many significant [autocorrelation] lags you have. If you have large lags, then choose a larger batch size, and if you have small lags choose a smaller batch size.

I have really small autocorrelation lags. In fact, I have no significant autocorrelation lag at all, possibly because I set a rather high thinning interval of 10,000 samples. Here's how my autocorrelation plot looks like for one parameter (all the others look the same):

[image: Autocorrelation plot for one of the parameters, generated with package coda]

Following @Greenparker's advice, I would think setting the batch size to the lowest possible value (batch size = 1) is a good idea. However, in the same post, she also notes that:

> If [batch size]=1, then the batch means will be exactly the Markov chain, and your batch means estimator will estimate Λ and not Σ.

So, on the one hand, I understand that I should use a low batch size if I have low autocorrelation lags. On the other, there seems to be disadvantages in using too low a batch size (although it is not clear to me if estimating Λ and not Σ is something that compromises the estimation of multivariate ESS).

My question is: should I set the batch size to 1 when I have no significant autocorrelation at all? If not, what would be a more recommendable value?

Comment: My answer to the linked question is only intuitively right. In principle, a fixed batch size will not yield theoretically appropriate estimates. The mcmcse R package has a batchSize() function that recommends a batchSize for the mulviariate batch means estimator. That is also the default in the multiESS() function in the package.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I noticed that the default batch size in multiESS() is the output of batchSize(). However, batchSize() returns a value of 0, causing the following error in multiESS(): `Error in mcse.multi(chain, ...) : Either decrease r or increase n`. I assume this is because n is below 1?

Comment: I am taking a look at the function batchSize() to see what might be going on. It imputes a value of 1 to `b` whenever `b == 0`, and then rounds down `b`. In the case of my chain, `b` is calculated as 0.23. It is not transformed into 1 (since `b != 0`) and then rounded down to 0. If the intention is to bound `b` to be above or equal to 1, this would work better if the imputation occurred whenever `b < 1`. Or, alternatively, if the imputation came after the rounding. Could that be the case?

Comment: That's an unfortunate error in the code, and thanks for pointing it out! In this case this implies that you're samples are essentially iid, which would mean that your multiESS  == your sample size n. In other words, batchSize() should've just returned 1.

Comment: The mcmcse GitHub repo has it fixed now. I'll push it on to CRAN in the near future: https://github.com/dvats/mcmcse

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and for fixing the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question because @Greenparker was kind enough to clarify it in the comments.

Ideally, I should use the function `batchSize` in package mcmcse to estimate the optimal batch size. That's the default option in `multiESS`. In my specific case, the optimal batch size happens to be 1, as originally asked.

(Beware that there is an error in function `batchSize` as available from CRAN (v1.4.1). This error allows the optimal batch size to be lower than 1, which shouldn't happen. The GitHub repo has it fixed: github.com/dvats/mcmcse)